# Asynhttpclient 'https' not allowed

Tags: android, api, http, android-studio, https

I'm using Asynhttpclient lib to execute api in android,which is not allow 'https' but it allow 'http' ,it show below error,

```
**Error :**
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Handshake failed
W:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:396)
W:     at cz.msebera.android.httpclient.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:535)
W:     at cz.msebera.android.httpclient.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:403)
W:     at cz.msebera.android.httpclient.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:472)
W:     at cz.msebera.android.httpclient.conn.scheme.SchemeSocketFactoryAdaptor.connectSocket(SchemeSocketFactoryAdaptor.java:65)
W:     at cz.msebera.android.httpclient.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:177)
W:     at cz.msebera.android.httpclient.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:145)
W:     at cz.msebera.android.httpclient.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:131)
W:     at cz.msebera.android.httpclient.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:611)
W:     at cz.msebera.android.httpclient.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:446)
W:     at cz.msebera.android.httpclient.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:860)
W:     at cz.msebera.android.httpclient.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
W:     at com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpRequest.makeRequest(AsyncHttpRequest.java:146)
W:     at com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpRequest.makeRequestWithRetries(AsyncHttpRequest.java:177)
W:     at com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpRequest.run(AsyncHttpRequest.java:106)
W:     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:423)
W:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
W:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
W:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
W:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
W: Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: SSL handshake terminated: ssl=0xb8635680: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error
W: error:100c5438:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:TLSV1_ALERT_INTERNAL_ERROR (external/boringssl/src/ssl/s3_pkt.c:972 0xb86b88b8:0x00000001)
W:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake(Native Method)
W:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:324)
W:  ... 19 more
```

Comment: Edit your question and add the url of the server you want to query and details on the used device.

Answer (score 0):

The logcat output says the url you are trying to hit does not have proper `ssl certificate` and therefore handshaking is failing. Just checking browsing that url or try doing curl it, you would get more insights.

Comment: thank you for response , first release it was 'http' and latterly it changed to 'https' . is there any solution to solve using Asynhttpclient libraries

Comment: change it to `http` might work otherwise u need to give the url